# Disable PushbuttonField in PDF using iText

Tags: java, itext

I have created **PDF** template using open office.I have added `PushButtonField` in it.Whenever user clicks on it all textfield data is being cleared *(Other form data should not be cleared)* .So How can I disable *(unclickable but visible)* PushButtonField using java or directly from open office.I have tried following two solutions but they are not working.

1) Set PushButtonField property "`Enabled`" to "`No`" in OpenOffice.

2) From Java access pushbuttonfield by id and set option to readonly.

```
ad.setOptions(BaseField.READ_ONLY)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Addition to Michaël Demey's answer- If you are using stamper then following is a solution-                                  
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.partialFormFlattening("component_Id");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could try is to partially flatten the form. By only passing the name of the button you want to make unclickable to "partialFormFlattening".

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(INPUT), new PdfWriter(OUTPUT));

PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(document, true);

form.partialFormFlattening(nameOfTheButtonField);
form.flattenFields();

document.close();
```

Comment: Glad to see it helped!